# Prevent server-side caching in wordpress when using file() function

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm displaying the most recent version of a simple .txt file on a wordpress page. This file is generated by other processes on the server (outside of wordpress) and can be updated every few seconds.

When using the example code below in functions.php, the server often returns an out-of-date version of the .txt. I assume that server-side caching is the culprit.

```php
$file = file(example.txt);
echo $file;
```

I want file() to return the current version of example.txt, not an outdated/cached file.

Note that I do not want to disable site-wide caching.

Comment: It might be many caching layers. Are you using wordpress caching plugins? It might be your server (apache, nginx, ...). Did you try: ```$handle = fopen("test.txt", "r");
$fileip = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

echo $fileip;
```

Comment: Thank you kindly @niklas. Will try these alternatives. I believe Jetpack is the only caching plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a version to the file name so the browser pulls it each time.

```
$version = time();

$file = file('example.txt?ver=' . $version);
```